# Duda con una consulta de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla Notificación, relacionada con una tabla "Solicitud" y una tabla "Tarea". Una solicitud puede tener varias tareas, pero quiero hacer una consulta en la que se muestre sólo la última tarea de cada solicitud. Pongo de ejemplo el sql que estoy haciendo:

```
    select DISTINCT solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD, tarea.ID_TAREA, solicitud.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_SOLICITUD, tarea.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_TAREA
from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION notificacion 
    inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
    left outer join TAREA_REPARACION as tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION 
    where solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD in (68433,68424,68769)
```

Esas 3 solicitudes por las que estoy filtrando tienen dos tareas y se muestran "duplicadas" en el listado:
[image: Imagen del listado con las solicitudes duplicadas]

Quiero que el resultado de eso fuera una línea por solicitud, cogiendo la información de la última tarea. ¿Es esto posible? He intentado hacerlo con una subconsulta en el from para las tareas pero me fallaba, intentando combinarlo con TOP pero solo me sacaba un registro...

Comment: cómo se sabe cuál es la última tarea?, alguna columna con fecha?

Comment: Hay una columna con fecha, pero digamos que lo que quiero es quedarme con la tarea que tenga un id más grande (dado que es un dato autoincrementado, el que mayor id tenga es el más reciente)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso lo que yo te recomiendo es que obtengas los máximos en una subconsulta, es igual a tu consulta normal solo agrupa por tu notificación y obtienes la ultima tarea.

Luego el resultado de tu subconsulta, lo cruzas vs tu tabla normal, por el id que ya traes en tu subconsulta.

El resto de la consulta ya es el resultado normal.

```
select DISTINCT solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD,
    tarea.ID_TAREA,
    solicitud.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_SOLICITUD,
    tarea.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_TAREA
from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION notificacion 
    inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
    LEFT JOIN (
       -- Aquí realizo el agrupado, por id de notificación y obtengo el ultimo item de las tareas
        SELECT notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION, max(tarea.ID_TAREA) ID_TAREA
        FROM NOTIFICACION_REPARACION AS notificacion
            inner join SOLICITUD AS solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
            INNER join TAREA_REPARACION as tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION
        where tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION in (68433,68424,68769)
        GROUP BY notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION
    ) UltimaTarea ON notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=UltimaTarea.ID_NOTIFICACION
    -- Realizo el cruce vs el id de la ultima tarea
    left join  TAREA_REPARACION AS tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION  and UltimaTarea.ID_TAREA = tarea.ID_TAREA
where solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD in (68433,68424,68769)
```

Comment: Esta sí que parece funcionarme como quería! Un millón de gracias! voy a probarlo en la consulta real que es bastante más grande, a ver si sale bien, y doy esta respuesta por buena de ser así

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer primero es el SELECT de los datos que ya sabes que están correctos, en este caso seria el siguiente

```
select solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD, max(tarea.ID_TAREA) from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION notificacion      inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD      left outer join TAREA_REPARACION as tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION      GROUP BY solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD
```

Posteriormente ese SELECT te servirá para hacer el JOIN a la misma tabla y así obtener el resto de datos ya filtrados, como se muestra a continuación:

```
select DISTINCT solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD,
    tarea.ID_TAREA,
    solicitud.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_SOLICITUD,
    tarea.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_TAREA
from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION AS notificacion 
    inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION, max(tarea.ID_TAREA)
        FROM NOTIFICACION_REPARACION AS notificacion
            inner join SOLICITUD AS solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
            INNER join TAREA_REPARACION AS tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION
        GROUP BY notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION
    )UltimaTarea ON notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=UltimaTarea.ID_NOTIFICACION
    left join  TAREA_REPARACION AS tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION  and UltimaTarea.ID_TAREA = tarea.ID_TAREA
```

Comment: Buenas! gracias por tu respuesta, sí, he probado, mismo resultado... El sql:
select DISTINCT solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD, tarea.ID_TAREA, solicitud.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_SOLICITUD, tarea.ID_ESTADO ESTADO_TAREA
from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION notificacion 
 inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
 left outer join TAREA_REPARACION as tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION 
where solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD in (68433,68424,68769)
ORDER BY ID_TAREA desc

Comment: La otra es que primero hagas el `select solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD, max(tarea.ID_TAREA)
from NOTIFICACION_REPARACION notificacion 
    inner join SOLICITUD solicitud on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD 
    left outer join TAREA_REPARACION as tarea on notificacion.ID_NOTIFICACION=tarea.ID_NOTIFICACION 
    GROUP BY solicitud.ID_SOLICITUD` y ya despues uses esos resultados como traer el resto de la info

Comment: Ostras eso sí que me funciona (al menos en esta versión "sencilla de la sql", en realidad es mucho más grande pero para preguntar por aquí he simplificado mucho el problema para entenderlo mejor). Muchísimas gracias, voy a probar a hacerlo para la sql grande digamos.

Comment: Claro, no hay de que.

Comment: hmm... Si añado por ejemplo la columna de estado de solicitud, me peta diciendo "Column 'SOLICITUD.ID_ESTADO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"... Entiendo el error pero no el por qué peta, si una solicitud tiene su estado, no es posible que haya más de un estado para una solicitud

Comment: Ahhh, porque el GROUP BY no deja hacer ese tipo de SELECT, el que te pase es para que lo uses como un JOIN a la tabla que quieres tomando el ID de los registros de dicho GROUP BY. De hecho es como te lo pasaron abajo, solo que sin los where para dejarlo más general.

Comment: Saludos @JaimeJonathanOrtizVelazco, esta no es una respuesta entiendo que no tengas suficiente reputación para realizar comentarios por favor lee [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-sitio/3765#3765). En todo caso veo que al parecer solucionaste el problema de OP, recuerda que siempre puedes editar tu respuesta para que sea marcada como correcta y así mismo ganes puntos de reputación. ;)

Comment: Listo @Israel-ICM, espero que así pueda ser mas entendible.